# How can I make all Buttons the same height and width when one of them is facebook LoginButton

Tags: android, xml, button, evenly

I want all `Buttons` to me the same height and width automatically. The Facebook `Button` however does not react to `android:layout_weight="1"`, and as I did in the code setting the `padding` for it will not work consistently.

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.port.android.ui.ActivityMain">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="20%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="70%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Some text about login" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_below="@+id/first"
        android:layout_above="@+id/second"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_with_facebook"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/login_with_facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_with_google"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/google_button_press"
            android:text="@string/login_with_google" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_with_twitter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/login_with_twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_with_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/login_with_password" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:layout_widthPercent="70%"
        app:layout_marginBottomPercent="5%"
        app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Some more text about login" />
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set layout_height="0dp" while using layout_weight attribute.

Comment: I try that but the facebook Butten height is not changed. This is not a normal    "Button". If I remove the padding it get really worse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can make some work around by making fb sdks login button visibility gone and taking ur own button just like u have used other 3. And onclick of new button fire the FB login buttons on click

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/fbLogin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtFBLogin"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/signup_fb_bg"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_facebook"
                android:drawablePadding="-20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/dimen_7dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: But [Brand Guidelines for Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/branding)

Comment: forbids me from doing this, using there logo, If my app get populäre it will give me problem maybe

Comment: i dont think there is any voilation in it, ur just using any other view/component which allows u to do the functionality and meet ur requirement.

Answer (score 0):

use this one:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_below="@+id/first"
    android:layout_above="@+id/second"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_with_facebook"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/login_with_facebook" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_with_google"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/google_button_press"
        android:text="@string/login_with_google" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_with_twitter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/login_with_twitter" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_with_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/login_with_password" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order your `layout_weight` to work properly you should set the `layout_height` of each of your `Buttons` to 0.

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_with_facebook"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/login_with_facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_with_google"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/google_button_press"
            android:text="@string/login_with_google" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_with_twitter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/login_with_twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login_with_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/login_with_password" />
```